# How do you define entropic energy?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, work, entropy

If the definition of energy is the ability to do work but entropy represents the amount of energy unavailable to do work how can we define this energy since it's unable to do work, therefore seemingly violating the definition of energy?

Answer (score 1):

We need to be clear with the terminology:

- entropy is *a measure* of the energy that is *unavailable* as work in a process that operates at *constant temperature, constant volume and constant mass*

In order to maintain the temperature of the system we need to commit a certain amount of energy which then becomes unavailable for other purposes. This amount is related to the entropy of the system. This energy *can* be converted to work, but then the temperature of the system would have to decrease.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense thank you!